# ItemUpdating remote event reciever is not firing

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, remote-event-receiver, item-updating

I am following the steps mentioned in this link to create a Remote Event Receiver inside our SharePoint online site collection @ https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/create-remote-event-receiver-sharepoint-online/

and inside the AppEventReceiver.svc i define to attach the app on ItemUpdated and ItemUpdating as follow:-

```
public class AppEventReceiver : IRemoteEventService
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles app events that occur after the app is installed or upgraded, or when app is being uninstalled.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name=”properties”>Holds information about the app event.</param>
        /// <returns>Holds information returned from the app event.</returns>

        public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
            if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled)
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
                {
                    if (clientContext != null)
                    {
                        //Get reference to the host web list with name Feedback
                        var documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Update System");
                        clientContext.Load(documentsList);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        string remoteUrl = "https://tpusrer.azurewebsites.net/Services/TPUSRemoteEventReceiver.svc";
                                                  //Create the remote event receiver definition
                        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation newEventReceiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
                        {
                            EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdated,
                            ReceiverAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                            ReceiverName = "TPUSRemoteEventReceiver",
                            ReceiverClass = "TPUSRemoteEventReceiver",
                            ReceiverUrl = remoteUrl,
                            SequenceNumber = 15002
                        };
                        //Add the remote event receiver to the host web list
                        documentsList.EventReceivers.Add(newEventReceiver);
                        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation newEventReceiver2 = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation()
                        {
                            EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdating,
                            ReceiverAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                            ReceiverName = "TPUSRemoteEventReceiver2",
                            ReceiverClass = "TPUSRemoteEventReceiver2",
                            ReceiverUrl = remoteUrl,
                            SequenceNumber = 15001
                        };
                        //Add the remote event receiver to the host web list
                        documentsList.EventReceivers.Add(newEventReceiver2);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.AppUninstalling)
            {
                using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
                {
                    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Update System");
                    clientContext.Load(list);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    EventReceiverDefinitionCollection erdc = list.EventReceivers;
                    clientContext.Load(erdc);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    List<EventReceiverDefinition> toDelete = new List<EventReceiverDefinition>();
                    foreach (EventReceiverDefinition erd in erdc)
                    {
                        if (erd.ReceiverName == "TPUSRemoteEventReceiver")
{
                            toDelete.Add(erd);
                        }
                    }

                    //Delete the remote event receiver from the list, when the app gets uninstalled

                    foreach (EventReceiverDefinition item in toDelete)
                    {
                        item.DeleteObject();
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is a required placeholder, but is not used by app events.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name=”properties”>Unused.</param>

        public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and when i check the remote event receivers attached to the list using this PnP script,i got the 2 RERs,:-

```
Get-PnPEventReceiver -List "Project Update System"
```

But when i update a list item, the ItemUpdated RER will work well, but the ItemUpdating will not have any effect. here is the code for the ItemUpdating RER:-

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
    int listItemID = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId;
    string siteUrl = properties.ItemEventProperties.WebUrl;

    SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
    string errormessage = "";

    using (ClientContext context = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
    {
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", listItemID);
        ListItemCollection collListItem = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Update System").GetItems(camlQuery);
        context.Load(collListItem);
        context.Load(collListItem,
              items => items.Include(
                  item => item.Id,
                  item => item["ProjectDescription"],
                  item => item["ProjectOMSNumber"],
                  item => item["ProjectDateSinged"],
                  item => item["ProjectManHoursEstimated"],
                  item => item["ProjectStage"],
                  item => item["ProjectApproveDelay"],
                  item => item["ProjectClosureSummary"],
                  item => item["ProjectHasBeenDelayed"],
                  item => item["ProjectDateSinged"],

                  item => item["ProjectHasBeenDelayed"],
                  item => item["ProjectStatusFlag"]
                  ));
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        context.Load(collListItem);

        foreach (ListItem i in collListItem)
        {
            //This for all the orders regardless if there are created from OMS or Manully7
            FieldUrlValue currenturl = i["ProjectLinkToOMS"] != null ? (FieldUrlValue)i["ProjectLinkToOMS"] : null;
            //var fff = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectLinkToOMS"];
            if (i["ProjectOMSID"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectOMSID"] != null && (i["ProjectOMSID"].ToString() != properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectOMSID"].ToString()))
            //||
            //(i["ProjectLinkToOMS"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectLinkToOMS"] != null && (!properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectLinkToOMS"].ToString().Contains(currenturl.Url+","+currenturl.Url))))
            {

                errormessage = errormessage + "Unaithorized access";
            }


            if (i["ProjectOMSID"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i["ProjectOMSID"].ToString()))//item created from OMS!
            {
                TaxonomyFieldValue currentcustomer = (TaxonomyFieldValue)i["ProjectCustomer"];

                if (
                   properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties.ContainsKey("ProjectDescription") && i["ProjectDescription"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"] != null &&
                    (
                    Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(i["ProjectDescription"].ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty), @"\p{C}+", String.Empty)
                    != Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"].ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty), @"\p{C}+", String.Empty)
                    )
                    )
                { errormessage = errormessage + "You are not authorized to update Description."; }

            }

            var vv = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectCustomer"];
            if (properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectStage"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectStage"].ToString() == "Closed" && (properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectManHoursUsed"] == null || properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectManHoursUsed"].ToString() == string.Empty))
            {
                errormessage = errormessage + "You must enter Man Hour used before closing the project";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errormessage))
            {


                result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
                result.ErrorMessage = errormessage;
            }

        }
    }

    return result;}
```

So can anyone advice why the ItemUpdating RER is not firing? although seems it is registered and attached to the list.

Comment: can you post the results you get when running `Get-PnPEventReceiver`?

Comment: Have you tried just wrapping the entire using statement in a try..catch to see if some error is prohibiting the handler from responding?

Answer (score 0):

Just for troubleshooting, I would start by adding a try..catch and using that to cancel the event if something goes wrong.  Let us know what result you get for trying something like this:

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
    int listItemID = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId;
    string siteUrl = properties.ItemEventProperties.WebUrl;

    SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
    string errormessage = "";

    try
    {
        using (ClientContext context = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
        {
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", listItemID);
            ListItemCollection collListItem = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Update System").GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.Load(collListItem);
            context.Load(collListItem,
                  items => items.Include(
                      item => item.Id,
                      item => item["ProjectDescription"],
                      item => item["ProjectOMSNumber"],
                      item => item["ProjectDateSinged"],
                      item => item["ProjectManHoursEstimated"],
                      item => item["ProjectStage"],
                      item => item["ProjectApproveDelay"],
                      item => item["ProjectClosureSummary"],
                      item => item["ProjectHasBeenDelayed"],
                      item => item["ProjectDateSinged"],

                      item => item["ProjectHasBeenDelayed"],
                      item => item["ProjectStatusFlag"]
                      ));
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            context.Load(collListItem);

            foreach (ListItem i in collListItem)
            {
                //This for all the orders regardless if there are created from OMS or Manully7
                FieldUrlValue currenturl = i["ProjectLinkToOMS"] != null ? (FieldUrlValue)i["ProjectLinkToOMS"] : null;
                //var fff = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectLinkToOMS"];
                if (i["ProjectOMSID"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectOMSID"] != null && (i["ProjectOMSID"].ToString() != properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectOMSID"].ToString()))
                //||
                //(i["ProjectLinkToOMS"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectLinkToOMS"] != null && (!properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectLinkToOMS"].ToString().Contains(currenturl.Url+","+currenturl.Url))))
                {

                    errormessage = errormessage + "Unaithorized access";
                }


                if (i["ProjectOMSID"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i["ProjectOMSID"].ToString()))//item created from OMS!
                {
                    TaxonomyFieldValue currentcustomer = (TaxonomyFieldValue)i["ProjectCustomer"];

                    if (
                       properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties.ContainsKey("ProjectDescription") && i["ProjectDescription"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"] != null &&
                        (
                        Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(i["ProjectDescription"].ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty), @"\p{C}+", String.Empty)
                        != Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectDescription"].ToString(), "<.*?>", String.Empty), @"\p{C}+", String.Empty)
                        )
                        )
                    { errormessage = errormessage + "You are not authorized to update Description."; }

                }

                var vv = properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectCustomer"];
                if (properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectStage"] != null && properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectStage"].ToString() == "Closed" && (properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectManHoursUsed"] == null || properties.ItemEventProperties.AfterProperties["ProjectManHoursUsed"].ToString() == string.Empty))
                {
                    errormessage = errormessage + "You must enter Man Hour used before closing the project";
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errormessage))
                {


                    result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
                    result.ErrorMessage = errormessage;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.CancelWithError;
        result.ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```